# Why does add-apt-repository now fail to retrieve keys behind my proxy server, but I can update package lists and manually receive the keys?

Tags: apt, proxy, repository, keyserver

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04 with the latest updates behind a proxy server at my school. I had no problem a few months ago. However, over the past two months when I try to add a repository with `add-apt-repository` there is no key retrieved. I can then use `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys KEY` with success, but this is annoying. I have created scripts that add PPAs, install software, and more that are now failing because of this issue.

Should I be filing a bug report? If so, could someone please direct me to where to file.

Here is what my terminal output looks like when trying to add the PPA for my-weather-indicator:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
 Applications from atareao
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~atareao/+archive/ubuntu/atareao
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp16ytp9px/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmp16ytp9px/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 36FD5529 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key A3D8A366869FE2DC5FFD79C36A9653F936FD5529 can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 36FD5529
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.fla11h2USs --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/steam.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 36FD5529
gpg: requesting key 36FD5529 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 36FD5529: public key "Launchpad PPA for atareao" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

**Update:** I was able to get it working with the `-E` parameter for sudo, so the command that works is `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao`. However, I don't understand why things worked without that before and now it does not. Also, this does not seem to explain why other commands with `sudo` work without the `-E` parameter. This solution comes from Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: That solution works, MadMike, but I don't understand why I did not need the `-E` a few months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are facing two problems:

1. `add-apt-repository` is relying on the existence of the correct `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` values.
2. `sudo` will not use all of the current environment values. Probably for security reasons. There are two possibilities how to overcome this:

   1. Call `sudo -E add-apt-repository <additional-options>`

      This will use all of the current environment.
   2. You can configure `sudo` to automatically copy `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` too. Do this:

      ```
      sudo visudo
      ```

      Add the following lines:

      ```
      Defaults env_keep +="http_proxy"
      Defaults env_keep +="https_proxy"
      ```

      Blantantly copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8636711/406423).

Comment: This all makes sense, but then why does `sudo apt-get update` work fine without any modification?

Comment: My guess is, that `apt-get` can fallback to reading `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*`-files and `add-apt-repository` doesn't. Unfortunately, this all just stuff I've looked up while wrestling with corporate proxy configurations. I don't have any first-hand "I've seen the code"-knowledge :-/

Comment: This makes the most sense from what I've read around the web. Thanks!